# How can I distinguish the use of a numerical value and the use of a #define with Clang?

Tags: c++, c, clang

Lately I've been working with Clang, and for certain purposes, I need to know when a typedef macro is used.

As far as I know, both ast-dump for the following codes are exactly the same for the variable declaration :

```
#define SIZE_MAX 16
int my_array[SIZE_MAX];
```

and

```
int my_array[16];
```

AST-dump is the following :

`VarDecl 0x1dbc370 <test.cpp:2:1, col:21> my_array 'int [16]'`

Of course, I know that a typedef is just an alias, but when `SIZE_MAX` is parsed, there must be some kind of redirection to get the `16` value.

So, how can I distinguish when a macro is called, and when it is not ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

---

In Clang, the AST nodes are tagged with a [SourceLocation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#the-sourcelocation-and-sourcemanager-classes) which, as the description in the link implies, encodes both *its spelling location and its instantiation location*.

Therefore, using the `SourceLocation` of a node in combination with a `SourceManager`, you should not only be able to know whether something came from a macro-expansion, or not, but in case it does you should also be able to retrieve the expansion stack...

... which is what happens [in diagnostics](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3929504a7b206ee6):

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 0

int Array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {};
```

yields:

```
main.cpp:3:11: warning: zero size arrays are an extension [-Wzero-length-array]
int Array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {};
          ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:1:20: note: expanded from macro 'ARRAY_SIZE'
#define ARRAY_SIZE 0
                   ^
1 warning generated.
```

Have a look at http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Frontend/DiagnosticRenderer.cpp and notably:

```
static StringRef getImmediateMacroName(SourceLocation Loc,
                                       const SourceManager &SM,
                                       const LangOptions &LangOpts) {
   assert(Loc.isMacroID() && "Only reasonble to call this on macros");
   // Walk past macro argument expanions.
   while (SM.isMacroArgExpansion(Loc))
     Loc = SM.getImmediateExpansionRange(Loc).first;
```

*(copied verbatim, with the typo in the comment)*

Comment: Ok I do understand that Macros are recorded with a particular `SourceLocation`, but I still didn't figure out haw can I get whether it is a numerical value or a macro that is used. With the soft I'm using (OCLint), I am able to jump in the code from `VarDecl` to the next `VarDecl` (because I'm only interested by `VarDecl`, for example). Now that I have this `VarDecl`, I am able to get the initializer as an `Expr *`, but then, I'm a bit lost ...

Comment: The `Expr` should have a [`getExprLoc`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Expr.html#ab4fa508722ecc1546ad73cb31b0dc06c) member.

Comment: Yes it does, but that suggests that the expression would always only be a macro, or only an integer value etc. 

What if there is a declaration `int i = SIZE_MAX + 5;` ?

Comment: @Marc-O: In this case, the expression should be a compound expression such as `CallExpr`. I am not aware of any better way than to use a visitor on `Expr*` to and operate on the whole tree; which is much more ambitious than what your original question hinted at. I am sorry, but my forays into Clang did not delve that deep.